# How to show post excerpts on WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, genesis

How do I get all my blog posts to show as shortened excerpts(?) as shown in [this theme demo](http://my.studiopress.com/themes/simply/#demo-full)? I'm using WordPress with a Genesis child theme. [This is my site](http://www.gleefulthings.com/blog/).

Answer (score 1):

You can usually change this in the Genesis Settings in the admin. Just go to the Genesis Theme settings and in there there is a section called Content Archives. In the display option, just select "Entry Excepts". That should do the trick